# Number of Atalassian XRay custom fields in Test Step

Tags: jira-xray

we need an information about the number of custom fields that we can add to default field in Test Steps.

Is there a version of Xray that allows us to add more than 3 custom fields in Test Step?

We installed a lower version (4.004) of XRay but we were able only to add 3 additional custom fields in the test steps (that seems to be the limit), but we need 6 additional fields.

Answer (score 0):

In Xray Cloud, you can have up to 6 test step fields, including the 3 default ones as detailed on [Xray documentation](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Project+Settings%3A+Test+Step+Fields).

However, if you aim to perform data-driven testing, you can create a [dataset](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUDDRAFT/Parameterized+Tests) instead at the Test level and there you can have to 20 parameters that you can reference inline on the test step fields.

Comment: Thanks Sérgio, we will manage them on Test level.

Comment: You're welcome. Appreciate if you can mark my answer as correct. Thanks and best of luck